# ogr2ogr from Postgres to GeoJSON missing crs key

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm using `ogr2ogr` to convert some OSM data for Greenland (not really important for the question), from a PostGIS database to a file containing GeoJSON.

The problem is that the GeoJSON gets written without the `crs` attribute, even though I'm reprojecting to a *non-4326* coordinate system (*3189* to be specific). See below how I do this.

The srid of data in geometry column in the database table is *4326*. I use the `t_srs "epsg:3189"` option to transform the coordinates, and this seems to work, i.e. the coordinates are not Lat/Lon.

**Command used**:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" greenland_coast.geojson \
  PG:"host=localhost user=xxx dbname=greenland_osm password=xxx" \
  -sql "select linestring from ways" -t_srs "epsg:3189"
```

**Snippet of GeoJSON result**:

Notice the missing `crs` attribute that should indicate that the coordinates are in [EPSG:3189](http://georepository.com/crs_3189/GR96-UTM-zone-29N.html).

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                         
"features": [
  { "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": { }, 
    "geometry": { 
      "type": "LineString", 
       "coordinates": [ 
         [ -548886.066167875193059, 9361706.390365654602647 ], ...]
     }
  },
  ...
]}
```

The coordinates seem to have been transformed correctly, but there is no crs field telling a reader of the GeoJSON file that the coordinates are in epsg:3189

The [GeoJSON spec](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#coordinate-reference-system-objects) states:

> If no crs member can be so acquired, the default CRS shall apply to
>   the GeoJSON object ... The default CRS is a geographic coordinate
>   reference system, using the WGS84 datum, and with longitude and
>   latitude units of decimal degrees.

I assumed that since I'm reprojecting to a non-geographic coordinate system, a `crs` key-value pair would be written to the GeoJSON (indicating EPSG:3189 in my case).

**My question**

Which of the following statements is more true?

- I'm using ogr2ogr wrong
- My expectations of ogr2ogr are too high
- There an error in the GeoJSON driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the OGR source, and I think option 2 applies.

```
#ifdef notdef
    if (poSRS)
    {
        const char* pszAuthority = poSRS->GetAuthorityName(NULL);
        const char* pszAuthorityCode = poSRS->GetAuthorityCode(NULL);
        if (pszAuthority != NULL && pszAuthorityCode != NULL && strcmp(pszAuthority, "EPSG") == 0)
        {
            json_object* poObjCRS = json_object_new_object();
            json_object_object_add(poObjCRS, "type", json_object_new_string("name"));
            json_object* poObjProperties = json_object_new_object();
            json_object_object_add(poObjCRS, "properties", poObjProperties);

            if (strcmp(pszAuthorityCode, "4326") == 0)
            {
                json_object_object_add(poObjProperties, "name", json_object_new_string("urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"));
            }
            else
            {
                /* FIXME?: the issue is that for geographic SRS, OGR will expose a latitude/longitude axis order */
                /* which is probably not what is written in the file! */
                json_object_object_add(poObjProperties, "name", json_object_new_string(CPLSPrintf("urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::%s", pszAuthorityCode)));
            }

            const char* pszCRS = json_object_to_json_string( poObjCRS );
            VSIFPrintfL( fpOut_, "\"crs\": %s,\n", pszCRS );

            json_object_put(poObjCRS);
        }
    }
#endif
```

That #ifdef notdef was added by [this commit](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/23662) but I couldn't say why.

Perhaps you can try rebuilding gdal without the #ifdef and #endif?

Comment: I see. So one approach is to hack the ogr2ogr source. Perhaps writing a script that post-processes the result and adds the crs is faster and at least more portable (although not ideal of course).

Comment: A bug report might also be worth a try?

Comment: I went ahead and filed a bug: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4995

Comment: And my bug ticket was marked fixed, looks like it'll be changed in the 1.10.0 release. Here's the patch: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/25665